# How to fix 'Unable to resolve property: id.element' Hibernate error when fetching with an @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, entity, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a method throwing the next error when querying a list of *Hibernate* entities while also fetching with a Join a *OneToOne* relation, having the child an *@EmbeddedId*  .

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Unable to resolve property: id.element; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve property: id.element

This is the query method:

```
public List<Element> findAll() {
  CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();

  CriteriaQuery<Element> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Element.class);
  Root<Element> root = criteriaQuery.from(Element.class);

  criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);

  root.fetch(Element_.elementSubstitute, JoinType.LEFT);

  return getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();;
}
```

This works fine when there are no resulting **elementSubstitutes**. Also similar methods work well for other *non-embedded-entities*, but these ones are mapped using an *@EmbeddedId* like this, which is why I think is the cause of the error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ELEMENT")
public class Element {

        //stuff

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "id.element", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private ElementSubstitute elementSubstitute;
}

@StaticMetamodel(Element.class)
public class Element_ {

    //stuff

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Element, ElementSubstitute> elementSubstitute;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ELEMENT_SUBSTITUTE")
public class ElementSubstitute {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ElementSubstituteId id = new ElementSubstituteId();

    //stuff
}

@Embeddable
public class ElementSubstituteId {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_OWNER")
    private Owner owner;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ELEMENT")
    private Element element;
}
```

Obtaining the **ElementSubstitute** from a single **Element** entity with *getElementSubstitute()* also works, so the mapping is not wrong and *Hibernate* is indeed able to recognize the property **id.element** when he wants to. Why is it failing when fetching with a join on a query?